# Can drone pilots use 1-800-WX-BRIEF?

Tags: regulations, faa, safety, united-states, weather

Can drone pilots call 1-800-WX-BRIEF to get weather information like pilots of crewed aircraft can?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a general FAA-related resource. The site is less helpful.  If calling - know your lingo.

But there are many better resources for drone flight management.  B4UFly and a good weather app are all I generally use.  I found the reference cited antiquated, difficult to use, and not as helpful as basic weather-tracking tools.

In general, I recommend a hard skip on that resource.